# Simple Javascript Math Function- addition/not working?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, math

This is my function:

```
var ans=(X*X)/(Y+Z);
```

When I enter `10`, `20`, and `10` - respectively- the addition bit comes out as `2010` and not `30`.
How can I fix this?

Comment: Because you're adding strings.

Comment: where is your code which assigns X, Y and Z ?

Answer (score 4):

Make sure to convert your strings to numbers first:

```
var X = "10";
var Y = "20";
var Z = "10";

X = +X; // unary plus operator converts to a number
Y = Number(Y); // or use the Number function
Z = parseInt(Z, 10); // or parseInt

var ans=(X*X)/(Y+Z);
```